# how to rename the bulk amount of file in directory through unix

Tags: unix, batch-rename

I have about 8000 files in a folder that all follow the same naming structure that I need to rename. If I can delimit by _ and ? then it should break the file name into what I'm looking for. Below is an example of the current file name and new file name. Any suggestions on how to do this

current file name
HQC014_CF1025.DAT_20200702232059_461555630.gz
HQC014_CF1026.DAT_20200702232102_461555611.gz
HQC014_CF1027.DAT_20200702233617_461559827.gz
HQC014_CF1028.DAT_20200702233619_461559848.gz
HQC014_CF1029.DAT_20200702233621_461559961.gz
HQC014_CF1030.DAT_20200702233622_461560000.gz
HQC014_CF1031.DAT_20200702233624_461560059.gz
HQC014_CF1032.DAT_20200702234624_461563363.gz
HQC014_CF1033.DAT_20200702235107_461564972.gz
HQC014_CF1034.DAT_20200702235108_461564975.gz
HQC014_CF1035.DAT_20200702235110_461564980.gz

New file name should be
CF1025.DAT
CF1026.DAT
CF1027.DAT
CF1028.DAT
CF1029.DAT
CF1030.DAT
CF1031.DAT
CF1032.DAT
CF1033.DAT
CF1034.DAT
CF1035.DAT

Comment: Hello! As noted in the `unix` tag's description, non-programming questions such as this should be directed to [Unix and Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of processing, you could use a small Bourne shell program:

```
for old_name in HQC014_*.gz; do
    new_name=${old_name#*_}        # Remove the prefix
    new_name=${new_name%%_*}       # Remove the suffix
    mv "$old_name" "$new_name"
done
```

Personally, I prefer using some dedicated tools like `mmv`:

```
mmv "HQC014_*.DAT_*.gz" "#1.DAT"
```

(make a backup of your files before executing any of those commands)